# Zen.Barcode.Code128 generates wrong barcode for consecutive lower case and upper case characters

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner

For the following code snippet :
   `Zen.Barcode.Code128BarcodeDraw cd128 = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum; Image barCode = cd128.Draw("mmZ5NEVJRa", 90 );`

The barcode produced scans as mmÚ5NEVJRa.

The Z is read as Ú.

I have noticed that the wrong character is always a capital letter followed by a lower case character. How do I fix this?

I tried to change the bar height but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: To know if the problem is caused by encoding or decoding, try with a different barcode reader/writer library. I tested using LEADTOOLS (Disclosure: I work for its vendor) and the [string "mmZ5NEVJRa" is encoded as this image](https://www.leadtools.com/support/publicforumimages/barcode128.png). I tested the image with both LEADTOOLS and a different barcode reader and they both gave the original string, indicating the encoding was correct. If you would like to try LEADTOOLS, you can download a free evaluation [from this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).